# Intellij Hotkey for marking regex checkbox on search/replace

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, hotkeys

I have a question that's been bugging me for quite some time now. I'd like to minimize my mouse usage while working in IntelliJ.

When doing searches (ctrl+f) or replacing text (ctrl+r) I always have to manually check the "Regex" checkbox when I want to use regex. Is there a quick way to toggle this checkbox with my keyboard, or do I always have to use my mouse for that?

Simply tabbing to the checkbox does not seem to be an option as using tab simply jumps between the search and replace input-boxes.

I can't seem to find anything in the keymap settings nor on google :(

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold `Alt`/`Option` button to see the mnemonics underscore. In my case I should use `Option x` to enable Regex.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Arwez note that it may not work if you have [disabled the mnemonics](https://i.imgur.com/6a9pygW.png). So make sure these options are not enabled.